# Rewriting image to page with adverisements

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

My mod-rewrite is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.png viewimg.php?n=$1 [NC]
```

So a user goes to `mysite.com/2012-10-16_1941.png` and it shows page `mysite.com/viewimg.php?n=2012-10-16_1941`.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['n'].".png";
    echo "<img src='".$_GET['n'].".png' alt='Image' />";
    echo "<br /><br />";
    echo "advert.";
?>
```

But, it takes that image that it's trying to embed and can't find it, because it's getting rewritten. How can I fix this, so that the image only shows on the PHP page?

I'm trying to make a PHP script like Gyazo uses, if you've ever heard of that. My desktop application uploads the screen capture to FTP, then I use this PHP script to display the image along with an advertisement. I just want a visually appealing URL to go along with it.

Comment: I don't see why you want to do this, it seems extremely circular but I guess you don't want people to hotlink your images or to just look at images. Well, you could base64 encode the image in the backend and then output render it on the page. I can't see any other workaround achieving your objective unless you use a specific key to access it which may be hashed based on the user's IP and some unknown salt.

Basically images can only be accessed using a URL like: /13917kfashfkasfas/image.png and the '13917kfashfkasfas' part is hashed when the page is rendered based on some factor.

Comment: @AshrayBaruah Are you familiar with Gyazo? I just want something like that - I already have my desktop application that uploads the file to FTP, but now I need to output it on a page that also displays an advertisement beside it.

Comment: Blindly outputting user input leads to [XSS vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding either a query string param or check against the referer:

### Query String:

php:

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['n'].".png";
    echo "<img src='".$_GET['n'].".png?embed' alt='Image' />";
    echo "<br /><br />";
    echo "advert.";
?>
```

mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} embed
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.png viewimg.php?n=$1 [NC]
```

### Referer Check

mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://mysite.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.png viewimg.php?n=$1 [NC]
```

php: no changes needed

Both can be spoofed to bypass your php page with adverts, but the query string one may work better across different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, html img tag src value could not take any html, it just take an image file path. so you can your code return an image file, with marked as advert(if this is what u want)